# Meaning of साम्ब ("Samba") with Sadashiva

Tags: scripture, shiva, name, durga, devi

In some prays to God Shiva, Like "[Shiva Aksharmala](http://www.hindudevotionalblog.com/2008/08/shiva-aksharamala-stotram-shri-samba.html)", there is prefix "Samba" (in Sanskrit सांब) is mentioned.

It seems the meaning of word "Samba" (सांब) is "attended by ambA"  **Source**: This [Link](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=sAmba&script=&direction=SE&link=yes)

Now, if we go purely by above meaning, then (सांब ) means one who is attended (probably means accompanied ) by Goddess "ambA".

Is this understanding correct and is there exist any scriptures where Lord Shiva is described as a "Saamba" (सांब)?

Comment: The understanding is correct. sAmba is sa+amba = with amba. The correct name is saamba; not saamb.

Comment: ya, thought so! Also, was looking for scripture ref. where there is more detailed explanation mentioned for reason behind such name being associated with Lord Shiva!

Comment: Various scriptural hymns such as the ashtottara , namakam etc. have this name. You can check the dictionary for the literal meaning of words in these hymns and commentaries by learned people for deeper meanings.

Comment: @WhisperingMonk: For the meaning, you can ask the question here : http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98070/sanskrit-language

Comment: Namaste
This post is in response to the question about scripture mentioning siva as sAmba.
I am translating Dakshinamurti Upanishad, and there is part of a mantra that says सांबशिवाय. (verse 8 / 14 depending on the reading...)
Kind regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Samba means Sa + Amba ie. Attended/ accompanied by Amba or With Amba.

> स + अम्बा = साम्ब (ie. With Amba) 
>   स + उमा = सोम (ie. With Uma) 
>   स + उमा + स्कन्ध = सोमस्कन्ध (ie. With Uma and Skandha)

The above all are names of Lord Shiva. Samba is frequently used in scriptures to denote Shiva and Shakti aspect simultaneously. They are used frequently in Linga Purana and Shiva Purana.

Here I give examples of Skandha Purana:

> एवमुक्त्वा महादेवः **साम्बः** संसारमोचक । 
>   सत्य ज्ञान परानन्दस्तत्रैवान्तरधीयत ।। 
>  
>   Mahadeva who is with Amba( ie. **Samba**) is the liberator of the world. He is truth, knowledge and infinite bliss. *[Skandha Purana Suta Samhita YajnaVaibhava Khanda]*

Also in Yajnabhaiva Khanda Sarva Shastra Sangrata, Suta Samhita; Skandha Purana:

> सर्वैश्वर्यैण संपन्न: सर्वेश सर्व कारणम् । 
>   शंभुरेव सदा **साम्बो** न विष्णुर्न प्रजापति ।। 25।। 
>  
>   Always with all Aishwarya, Lord of All and cause of All. Such is Sambhu who is with Amba (**Samba**). Neither Vishnu nor Prajapati (Brahma) are like that.

Also in the same place,

> शिवंकरत्वं संपूर्णं शिवस्यैव परात्मन: । 
>   **साम्बमूर्तिधरस्यास्य** जगतः कारणस्य हि ।। 27।। 
>  
>   Everything is Shiva itself. Shiva is the Supreme Soul itself. **He creates the form accompanied by Amba (ie. Samba form) just to be the cause of creation.**

Answer (score 6):

Krishna's Samba was born by the grace of Lord Shiva. Lord Krishna wanted to end Yadava clan as He thought no human could win their invincible sons. Actually, [Yadavas were attendants of Lord Vishnu in Vaikunta](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-47/topic-1) who incarnated as Yadavas to assist him in removing evil from Earth. So, Lord Krishna performed Pasupata Vrata to gain a son like Lord Shiva, so that He could destroy his clan as Lord Shiva is God of Destruction.

[This chapter of Shiva Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9995/3500) explains meaning of His name.

> Krishna of composed mind obtained his son Samba of good qualities
> bequeathed by Siva who was delighted by penance.Since **it was Shiva
> accompanied by Amba, who blessed him with a son**, **he named
> Jambavati's son Samba.**

[Chapter 70 of Matsya Purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-70/topic-1) mentions Shamba as Shiva Himself. Samba is epithet of Lord Shiva as explained by you in question. So, your understanding is correct.