# How did Samba, Krishna's son, get relieved from Curse of Krishna?

Tags: krishna, sin, surya

Samba was Lord Krishna and Jamabavati son. Samba was born from [Amsa of Lord Shiva.](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-70/topic-1) Lord Krishna wanted to end His Yadava clan (who were [attendants of Lord Vishnu in Vaikunta](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/matsya-mahapurana/vol-i/chapter-47/topic-1)) as His innumerable invincible Sons could never be defeated by normal Human Kings.

Krishna did [Pasupata vrata for 12 months](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9995/3500) to attain a Son like Rudra (the Lord of Destruction). Lord Shiva with Parvathi in Ardhanariswara form bestowed Krishna a son and they named him as "Samba". Samba was [indirectly responsible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(Krishna%27s_son)) for end of Yadava Clan.

Some of the [Junior wives of Krishna were attracted to Samba](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11806/3500) and due to this heinous act, Krishna cursed Samba to get affected by Leprosy.

Did Samba get relieved from this Curse? If so, how did he do it?

Comment: What is an amsa?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Samba got relieved from Curse of Krishna (disease of Leprosy) by praying to Lord Surya, as per suggestions of Narada.

This is mentioned in Bhavishya Purana, [Varaha Purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/25249/43f_chapter_177.pdf) and Samba Purana which are basis for Surya Worship.

On seeing the deplorable condition of Samba, Narada suggested Samba a method to get rid of sins and remedy of the curse of Krishna.

> Narada said:
>
> The result that is obtained by worshipping the Sun-god at the eastern
> mountain is obtained by worshipping him at Şaţsărya in Mathură.
> Worshipping him there in the noon and evening confers even a kingdom.
> **Reciting the mantras of the Sun in the morning, noon and evening at Mathura, one gets all sins removed. By worshipping the Sun after
> bathing in Krsnaganga, all sins disappear and so also all diseases
> like leprosy.**

Samba did exactly what Narada said and Lord Surya finally appeared before Samba.

> 44. He worshipped the rising sun at Satsurya according to the rules given by Narada.
> 45. Then, by yogic power, the Sun appeared before Samba and asked him to seek a boon for his good and for the establishment of the
>     Sūryavrata.
> 46. “Recite before me the fifty Slokas strung with expressions from the Vedas with which I was propitiated by Narada. I am pleased by your
>     worshipping me'.
> 47. **He was then touched by the Sun-god and soon he regained his wellshaped form and appeared like another Sun-god.**
> 48. The Sun then taught Samba the sacrifice of Yājñavalkya called 'Madhyandiniyaka to be performed at noon whence he is Madhyandina.
> 49. There is the tirtha Madhyandiniyaka on the western side of Vaikuntha (tirtha). To bathe there and see Madhyandina is to get free
>     from all sins.
> 50. The all-pervading Sun remained with Samba in the morning and evening, and in the evening he stood on the southern side of
>     Krsnaganga.
> 51. To see the Sun there in the morning and evening is to get removed of all sins and to attain Brahman.
> 52. **Thus appearing before Samba by splitting himself by the power of yoga from the sky, the Sun removed leprosy which was afflicting him.**

Samba also consecrated temple for Surya there.

> He then consecrated Surya in the rising form at Udayacala to the south
> of Yamuna, in the fully brilliant form at noon at Kalapriya and in the
> setting form at Astamanacala in Mulasthāna.  Thus he consecrated Sūrya
> in his three forms pertaining to morning, noon and evening.

Answer (score 0):

This story is also mentioned in the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa besides other scriptures.

Skandamahāpurāṇam Chapters [7.1.100](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626888.html) & [7.1.101](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626889.html) discusses this.

> [Chapter 100](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626888.html) - Durvāsas Curses Sāṃba,
> Prabhāsa-kṣetra-māhātmya,
> Prabhāsa Khaṇḍa
>
> Īśvara said:
>
> > 10. **Sāṃba** was born as his powerful son of Jāṃbavatī. **Vehemently cursed by his father, he contracted the fell disease of leprosy. The Sun-god
> >     was installed by him and a city was built after his own name.**

And in the next chapter we have the narration of how Sāṃba propitiate God Surya to alleviate his leprosy curse.

> [Chapter 101](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626889.html#note-t-163191) - Greatness of Sāṃbāditya (Sāṃba-āditya),
>
> Prabhāsa-kṣetra-māhātmya, Prabhāsa Khaṇḍa
>
> Īśvara said:
>
> > **After cursing the women Kṛṣṇa cursed Sāṃba too:**
>
> > 41. “Since, on perceiving your extremely attractive features all these women became agitated, you do be afflicted by the disease of leprosy.”
>
> > - 44-45. After having said thus to the lotus-eyed Kṛṣṇa Sāṃba was
> >   overcome with anxiety and grief. He was disgusted with everything. He
> >   then went to the Prabhāsa Kṣetra that destroys all sins. After
> >   reaching that holy place, he practised a very severe penance.
>
> > 46. He installed Lord Sun, the thousand-rayed deity, who destroys sins. Then he propitiated it fully conforming to the (prescribed)
> >     rules and restrictions.
>
> ....
>
> Sāṃba said:
>
> > 53. O most excellent one among Suras, I have been cursed by Kṛṣṇa. I am a sinner with a defiled mind; O Lord, if you are pleased with me,
> >     heal completely the fell disease of leprosy.
>
> Śrī Bhānu (the Sun-god) said:
>
> > 54. **O highly fortunate one, you shall be free from ailments, once again, with my favour you will be in the same form as you were in
> >     before.**