# Way of offering prayer to the Supreme

Tags: prayer

I heard sadhguru saying in a video that in our religion we pray for specific things through bhagwan like saraswati devi for *vidya and gyan*, durga devi for *victory, courage, ...*.

My question is: Do we find any such explicit mention in our scripture or can we establish above thing by observing various prayers offered in our scripture?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might want to consider clarifying on what exactly you are looking for as an answer. Are you looking for instances where it states worship of such and such devata gives certain benefits? Or like which devata worship gives what benefit?

Comment: partially related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23882/12304 Q..can you please make ur Q bit clearer?