# Whom do I worship?

Tags: gods, worship

I am really confused now, which god one should worship.
Is that one should worship all the gods? 
or according to ones needs, or ones material nature?

Comment: God is One, having many forms.The form that attracts you the most could be your chosen deity. Kabirji said : ek saadhe savi saadhe, sab saadhe sab jaaye' : Who worships one, worship all. who worships many loses all.

Comment: puja of any form can be sakama ie to get something or niskama ie to get vision of God and have pure devotion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do Hindus decide which gods or goddesses to worship?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14863/how-do-hindus-decide-which-gods-or-goddesses-to-worship) and [How do you find out your Ishta-Deva (personal deity)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2316/how-do-you-find-out-your-ishta-deva-personal-deity)