# How to find my guru

Tags: mantras

How can one find his guru, we do not have guru-sishya practice does not run in the family and not much of a

Have learnt that a guru appears whenever the sishya is ready but have been waiting for a long time, how does one identify or approach a guru.

Would like to learn about ishta devatha and do service to ishta devata under the guidance of a guru.

Comment: The toughest question that only the Almighty God can answer :-). It depends on many permutations and combinations.  1) it depends on maturity of the individual concerned 2) his/her prArabdha must have been cleared to a greater extent, such that the individual concerned will not be dragged back by his/her karma, and so on.

Comment: So better to wait for the God to show the designated Guru for the individual concerned.   As far as I understood,  instead of running from one fake or self declared Guru to another ,  better to do nAma japa,  recitation of one name of God,  say **rAma**, for certain number of times daily,  say 108 or 1008 times,etc, at one's place.   Fake or self declared Gurus are order of the day.   Beware of them.

Comment: pray to God intensely, not once, not one day or two days. Don't stop. Your guru will find you.

Comment: Ishta devta can be found in your Vedic horoscope. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36658/16530

Comment: Related [How do I find the right Guru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2394/3500)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the right Guru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2394/how-do-i-find-the-right-guru)

Answer (score 1):

The following are excerpts from the teachings of [Sri Ramana Maharishi.](https://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/teachings/%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%93/)

> D.: Is not Grace the gift of the Guru?
>
> M.: God, Grace and Guru are all synonymous and also eternal and
> immanent. Is not the Self already within? Is it for the Guru to bestow
> It by his look? If a Guru thinks so, he does not deserve the name.
>
> The books say that there are so many kinds of initiations – by hand,
> by touch, by eyes and by mind. They also say that the Guru makes some
> rites with fire, water, japa, mantras, etc., and call such fantastic
> performances Initiation, as if the disciple becomes ripe only after
> such processes are gone through by the Guru.
>
> D. How is the Guru found?
>
> M. God, who is immanent, in His grace takes pity on the loving devotee
> and manifests Himself according to the devotee’s development. The
> devotee thinks that He is a man and expects a relationship as between
> two physical bodies. But the Guru, who is God or the Self incarnate,
> works from within, helps the man to see the error of his ways and
> guides him in the right path until he realizes the Self within.
>
> D. What should the devotee do then?
>
> M. He has only to act up to the words of the Master and work within.
> The Master is both ‘within’ and ‘without’, so He creates conditions to
> drive you inward and at the same time prepares the ‘interior’ to drag
> you to the Centre. Thus He gives a push from ‘without’ and exerts a
> pull from ‘within’, so that you may be fixed at the Centre.