# Who is Maa Gouri?

Tags: goddess, devi, shaktism

I used a website to see what my birth chart says about my ishta deva/devi. I am most connected with Durga, but my results said Goddess Mahalakshmi and Maa Gouri.

Comment: Most astrological sites are fake as they are exaggerated claims to please viewers and trap them later. Ishta deva is found using 12th house of Karakamsa as explained in BPHS. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36658/20089 If 12th house is empty, lord of lagna, rashi,constellation, atmakaraka etc., will have impact on choosing ishta and his/her specific form by an individual.

Answer (score 1):

[Maa Gouri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gowri_Habba), the mother of Ganesha and wife of Shiva. Gouri is the incarnation of Aadhi Shakthi. [Gouri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahagauri) is the eighth manifestation of goddess Durga and amongst the Navadurgas. Also known as Parvati, daughter of Parvatha raj 'Himavat' and 'Menavati'.